# SPFX webpart Error: The value for "Custom field key" must not be undefined

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework

The sharepoint framework webpart with custom property stops working all the sudden and displaying this error message:

```
sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_36f8e2c….js:254 Uncaught (in promise) Error: ***The value for "Custom field key" must not be undefined
at Function.e.isNotNullOrUndefined (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2017-06-16.015/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_36f8e2c2f3b738608cda74036a78fd8d.js:254:1058)
at Function.e.isNonemptyString (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2017-06-16.015/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_36f8e2c2f3b738608cda74036a78fd8d.js:254:1163)
at t._renderGroupField (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2017-06-16.015/0.sp-webpart-base-propertypane_671c25e8d6f780a9556d.js:1:28447)
at https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2017-06-16.015/0.sp-webpart-base-propertypane_671c25e8d6f780a9556d.js:1:28259
at Array.map (native)
at t._renderGroupContent (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2017-06-16.015/0.sp-webpart-base-propertypane_671c25e8d6f780a9556d.js:1:28234)
at t.render (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2017-06-16.015/0.sp-webpart-base-propertypane_671c25e8d6f780a9556d.js:1:26942)
at p._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2017-06-16.015/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_36f8e2c2f3b738608cda74036a78fd8d.js:155:50265)
at p._renderValidatedComponent (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2017-06-16.015/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_36f8e2c2f3b738608cda74036a78fd8d.js:155:50392)
at performInitialMount (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2017-06-16.015/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_36f8e2c2f3b738608cda74036a78fd8d.js:155:46233)
```

What is `Error: The value for "Custom field key" must not be undefined` means? And how do I add the Custom field key?

The same issue is posted here:
https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/674

Comment: Is this only in the workbench, or does it happen on a normal page as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for raising the concern.

The reason you are seeing this is when you create a custom field you have to provide a unique `key` to it. This property is there for some time now and it was always a `required` field. The recent change we made in this regard is that we are now validating it to have a non-empty value. The reason we had to validate is that it introduces an issue while rendering the custom fields on the property pane. If you are passing an `undefined` or `null` or `empty` value for the `key` prop then you will see this error.

> /**
>
> A UNIQUE key indicates the identity of this control.
>
> The PropertyPane uses ReactJS to render its components. ReactJS uses keys to identify a component and if it should be re-rendered or not. This is a performance feature in ReactJS. Please read the following link to understand how to pick the value of the key.
>
> @see https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys
>
> */
>
> key: string;

So, the resolution for this would be that you have to pass in a **non-empty** value for that prop.

Please let me know if you need any more guidance in this regard.

Thanks for understanding,

Srikanth